# Can we use Nuxt as SPA only?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, single-page-application, nuxtjs3

I am currently using Angular + nodejs as my main tech stack...
I am interested in Vue, had a few simple projects with that, and saw a few videos about Nuxt3.
Does Nuxt3 support SPA applications (with nodejs API), or not?
If not, will it support SPA in the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nuxt is a super set of Vue, meaning that it can do everything that Vue does but will add more capabilities on top of it.

As [shown here](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/deployment#client-side-only-rendering), you can totally use Nuxt3 as an SPA by adding the following to the `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false
})
```

Still, I recommend using at least SSG or SSR to get some SEO/rendering benefits.

Comment: But what command do you need for creating the spa? `$ npm run generate` or `$ npm run build`?

Comment: @katerlouis `build` is for an SSR app, since SPA can be fully static you don't need a server to render it on demand. The good one to use is `generate` (it will build it at build-time when pushing your code).

Comment: But the generate command will generate all pages file to html, this is more like SSG than SPA. With SPA mode, we only need 01 file `index.html`, not all route pages.